# Indented addendums using BibLaTeX sourcemaps

Tags: biblatex, biber, annotations, biblatex-sourcemap

I'm trying to produce an annotated bibliography, with a summary paragraph for each entry, such that the addendum for each bibentry appears on a new line one indentation level deeper than the entry itself.

For each entry with

```
addendum = {Text.}
```

the following seems to work well, producing exactly the output format I want to see:

```
addendum = {\paragraph\indent{Text.}\\}
```

I'm trying to perform automatic conversion with the following:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=addendum, 
                match=\regexp{(.*)},
                fieldset=addendum,
                replace={\\paragraph\{\\indent $1\} \\}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the characters escaped correctly in the replace field, and LaTeX produces the error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.68 }
```

I can't make heads or tails of this - am I defining the output regex incorrectly?

EDIT: Minimum working example:

test.bib

```
@article{test,
  author    = {Luigi P. Cordella and
               Pasquale Foggia and
               Carlo Sansone and
               Mario Vento},
  title     = {A (Sub)Graph Isomorphism Algorithm for Matching Large Graphs},
  journal   = {{IEEE} Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {10},
  pages     = {1367--1372},
  year      = {2004},
  doi       = {10.1109/TPAMI.2004.75},
  timestamp = {Sat, 12 Mar 2016 09:04:02 +0100},
  addendum = {This is a test of simple annotations.}
}

@article{test2,
  author    = {Luigi P. Cordella and
               Pasquale Foggia and
               Carlo Sansone and
               Mario Vento},
  title     = {A (Sub)Graph Isomorphism Algorithm for Matching Large Graphs},
  journal   = {{IEEE} Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {10},
  pages     = {1367--1372},
  year      = {2004},
  doi       = {10.1109/TPAMI.2004.75},
  timestamp = {Sat, 12 Mar 2016 09:04:02 +0100},
  addendum = {\paragraph\indent{\textbf{Annotation:} This is a test of simple annotations using biblatex.}\\}
}
```

test.tex

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\bibliography{test}

% Sourcemap is placed here.

\begin{document}

Test 1 \cite{test}
Test 2 \cite{test2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

where test 1 is the pre-transformation citation, and test 2 is the desired output.

Comment: Minimum example of the document given -- is this along the right lines? @CarLaTeX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `\DeclareSourcemap`, a simple

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{addendum}{\paragraph\indent{\textbf{Annotation:}\addspace#1}\\}
```

is sufficient:

```
\documentclass{article} % [a4] is not a correct option
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{test,
    author    = {Luigi P. Cordella and
        Pasquale Foggia and
        Carlo Sansone and
        Mario Vento},
    title     = {A (Sub)Graph Isomorphism Algorithm for Matching Large Graphs},
    journal   = {{IEEE} Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
    volume    = {26},
    number    = {10},
    pages     = {1367--1372},
    year      = {2004},
    doi       = {10.1109/TPAMI.2004.75},
    timestamp = {Sat, 12 Mar 2016 09:04:02 +0100},
    addendum = {This is a test of simple annotations.}
}
@article{test2,
    author    = {Luigi P. Cordella and
        Pasquale Foggia and
        Carlo Sansone and
        Mario Vento},
    title     = {A (Sub)Graph Isomorphism Algorithm for Matching Large Graphs},
    journal   = {{IEEE} Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.},
    volume    = {26},
    number    = {10},
    pages     = {1367--1372},
    year      = {2004},
    doi       = {10.1109/TPAMI.2004.75},
    timestamp = {Sat, 12 Mar 2016 09:04:02 +0100},
    addendum = {This is a test of simple annotations using biblatex.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes} % added
% New format for addendum field
\DeclareFieldFormat{addendum}{\paragraph\indent{\textbf{Annotation:}\addspace#1}\\}
\addbibresource{test.bib} % Not \bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

Test 1 \cite{test}
Test 2 \cite{test2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I've also changed some code lines of your mwe, see comments.

Comment: Awesome, this works exactly as needed! It's simple enough to modify if I need to change the formatting in future. I'll apply the other changes you've suggested, too. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KyleSimpson You are welcome! BibLaTeX is very flexible! I've edited my answer to remove `natbib=true`, maybe it is not necessary for you.